Why are DSSP and STRIDE considered reference algorithms, and why do people continue to use them?
I am working on globular protein secondary structure assignments. The purpose of my project is to design an improved algorithm for secondary structure assignment.
I know two tools: DSSP and STRIDE for secondary structure prediction and assignment.
However, their accuracy [the Q3 (Q8) accuracy is defined as the percentage of residues for which the predicted secondary structures are correct] is around 53% and 70%, respectively, which isn't much if we compare them to modern algorithms like PALSSE, etc.
If so, why are DSSP and STRIDE considered reference algorithms, and why do people continue to use them?

This question is not specific enough. Please add more context to your post to describe a specific bioinformatics problem. Generic "What's the best tool" questions are better asked in discussion-type places like Reddit.

Note OP has edited the question.

What does accuracy mean in this context? Comparison to human assignment? 53% for DSSP seems low to me.

@jgreener, The Q3 (Q8) accuracy is defined as the percentage of residues for which the predicted secondary structures are correct.

But what is the source of ground truth? DSSP and STRIDE assign secondary structure from tertiary structure rather than predict it from sequence. I see the number 53% for DSSP in the PALSSE paper, but that is not for Q3 or Q8 accuracy.

@jgreener, then make some correction in the OP, and post an answer.
